# Proper MVVM implementation of MahApp's DialogCoordinator using MVVM Light

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, mvvm-light, mahapps.metro

I'm currently working on a project using `MahApps` and `MVVM Light`.
Currently, my solution is split into:

- `MyProject.Presentation`, which is a WPF app with `MahApps` installed
- `MyProject.Core`, which is a class library containing `MVVM Light`, ViewModels, ...

`MahApps` comes with a `DialogCoordinator` class and an `IDialogCoordinator` interface to be injected into my ViewModels located at `MyProject.Core`.

But, in order to inject the `IDialogCoordinator` interface into my ViewModels like this, ...

```
private readonly IDialogCoordinator _dialogCoordinator;

public MyViewModel(IDialogCoordinator dialogCoordinator)
{
    _dialogCoordinator = dialogCoordinator;
}
```

... I'd have to install `MahApps` on my `MyProject.Core` project, which I wanted to keep separated from any UI related stuff.

Is there a way to avoid that? Or do I have to compromise at that point?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Write your own version of the interface and use that. In your UI you can provide an implementation that uses the MahApps coordinator.

Comment: @Will Thank you very much, that solved my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always abstract away the abstraction with your own abstraction.

That is, provide an interface similar to IDialogCoordinator, then in your UI you can provide an implementation that uses DialogCoordinator to coordinate with the dialog.

And I'm my own grandpa.